# Need help, importing Json into my html, via Python & AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax

I'm pretty new to AJAX and it's been a while working with JS, with that being said, I'm working with Python to produce Valid JSON data, but the buck stops there.  Can someone please get me started in a direction, when I inspect the element, I can see the Json object, I'm lost from there and this is where I need help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Machine Check</h2></div>

<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="id01"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.gogleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <ul></ul>
    <script>
        /*
        $.getJSON('check.json', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            });
            */
        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                }
            });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where you have valid JSON data ?

Comment: {"Machines": [{"client1": 5, "upcli3": 1, "upcli2": 5, "upcli": -9}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json_object = JSON.parse(data)
// for json_object {"Machines": [{"client1": 5, "upcli3": 1, "upcli2": 5, "upcli": -9}]} 
// you can get values from object like below
var array = json_object.Machines
var client1 = array[0].client1 // it will be 5
```

JSON.parse() function will return a json object.

Comment: I apologize, but this is where my limited javascript knowledge comes into play, I assume this would be within the same script?  If you have any links that describe what you're instructing me to do, I'll be more than happy to catch up on it.  I'm getting:  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o "  when I insert it where I think it should go...

Comment: Ok, so I looked up the error for Uncaught Syntax Error, and it referred to the JSON already being parsed, so now, I did get past that, but now instead of what I wanted returned, I get '[object Object]'.  I think I can get past this part because I saw this somewhere earlier in my research.  I greatly appreciate your help as you put me that much closer to where i'm trying to get to...

Comment: You can try this . 
success : function(data) {
    
var array = data.Machines
var client1 = array[0].client1 // it will be 5
var client1 = array[0].client1 // it will be 5}